# Module '"hardhat"' has no exported member 'ethers'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hardhat

When I want to import `ethers` from `hardhat` it throws the error that I mentioned in the title here is a complete version

```
 - error TS2305: Module '"hardhat"' has no exported member 'ethers'.
 
     2 import { ethers } from "hardhat";
                ~~~~~~
```

Although I used it the same way in my previous projects and seen everyone doing the same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to add these two lines to `tsconfig.json`

```
  "include": ["./src", "./scripts"],//only the "scripts" part.
  "files": ["./hardhat.config.ts"]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how the issue was resolved on my side:

1. I added '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers' dependency by running `npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers`
2. `import @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers`
3. `ethers` now becomes available from 'hre' as it `ethers` is sort of injected into `hre`:
   so the code snippet:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai'
import hre from 'hardhat'
import {Contract} from 'ethers'
import '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers'

describe('SocialRecovery', function () {
  let fooBar: Contract
  beforeEach(async function () {
    const foobar = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('FooBar')
  })
})
```

Turns out `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers` exists as separated plugin that is 'injected' into 'hre' named import from 'hardhat' package.

I hope this helps, the other two answers did not work for me.

Happy coding,
WAGMI!

Answer (score 3):

`import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers"` to my hardhat.config.js/ts file solve this issue for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `tsconfig.json` in your root project containing

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On my end the issue was resolved by running **tsc --init** (turns out I have forgotten to initialize the typescript compiiler and generate the tsconfig.json file in my root dir)

Answer (score 0):

I have this strange problem also.

Yet, I have build the project using `npx hardhat` and indicating TS on the prompt.

For some days, it was ok but today, it breaks for not obvious reasons.

I have verified that my tsconfig.json was ok, and that in package.json, I have only this 2 dependencies in package.json, like a fresh new hardhat project (@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox and hardhat).

After some try and errors, I noticed that I mixed the use of yarn and npx.

So I removed all generated dirs (node_modules, typechain-types, artifacts, cache), all .lock file (package-lock.json and/or yarn.lock), and try using only npx and npm commands.

```
npm install
npx hardhat compile
npx hardhat node
etc..
```

And now, it works.
I don't know why this can happen, because for me yarn has the same effects as npx, but it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error while importing ethers from hardhat in hardhat. its because as you are using TS and you have not included TS files and folders like  hardhat config file in your tsconfig file like :

```
"include": ["./deploy/*.ts", "./test/*.ts", "./scripts/*.ts"],
"files": ["./hardhat.config.ts"]
```

add folders name in include and files name in files.

Answer (score -1):

They likely don't explicitly export ethers. In the documentations it shows using ethers in the following way:

```
import hre from "hardhat";

const Lock = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Lock");
```

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/test-contracts

Comment: I think you should have hre.ethers there too. hre.((etheres)) doesn't make much sense

Comment: I know. I just added parentheses to bolden the part where it throws the error.

Comment: did you import hre? Did you add the dependancy? Are you on the correct version?

Comment: Your syntax is identical to the syntax in the question.

Comment: They say in the HardHat doco at https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/hardhat-runtime-environment#accessing-the-hre-from-outside-a-task that you'd use `hre` so you can use Mocha for testing instead of `npx hardhat test`.